# Failed to init Reactor's debug agent at org.springframework.boot.reactor.DebugAgentEnvironmentPostProcessor

Tags: java, docker, google-cloud-platform, spring-webflux, google-cloud-run

I am using webflux and trying to host on GCP cloud run and getting the error below

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to init Reactor's debug agent
    at org.springframework.boot.reactor.DebugAgentEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(DebugAgentEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:374)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:332)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at com.sigma.news.SigmaApplication.main(SigmaApplication.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.reactor.DebugAgentEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(DebugAgentEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:49)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not self-attach to current VM using external process
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.installExternal(ByteBuddyAgent.java:695)
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:626)
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:606)
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:558)
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:535)
    at reactor.tools.agent.ReactorDebugAgent.init(ReactorDebugAgent.java:56)


    "java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to init Reactor's debug agent
    at org.springframework.boot.reactor.DebugAgentEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(DebugAgentEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:374)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:332)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at com.sigma.news.SigmaApplication.main(SigmaApplication.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.reactor.DebugAgentEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(DebugAgentEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:49)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not self-attach to current VM using external process
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.installExternal(ByteBuddyAgent.java:695)
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:626)
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:606)
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:558)
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:535)
    at reactor.tools.agent.ReactorDebugAgent.init(ReactorDebugAgent.java:56)
```

I am using the below docker file to run the application

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-oracle

WORKDIR /app

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline

COPY src ./src

CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

this spring boot project is running without errors at local with docker run it is showing the above issue when using google cloud run from google cloud build. how can I resolve the issue?

Comment: How you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try (!) running it under `gen2` available with `gcloud beta run deploy ... --execution-environment`.

See: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-execution-environments#choose

IIUC (!?) Cloud Run virtualizes syscalls. `gen1` uses one mechanism (gVisor?) and `gen2` another.

I've experienced issues very occasionally wherein a container will run elsewhere but not on Cloud Run `gen1`. Next time that happens, I'm going to try `gen2` but I've not yet had the opportunity.